# Why echo $1 return empty output in the bash shell even if I passed an argument to it?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Look at the interactive shell below.

```bash
mcd ()
{
echo $1
}
mcd abc
#>>> abc
echo $1
#>>>
```

I have known that `source` do not create the child process. So why `mcd abc` expand `$1` to abc while `echo` doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

The positional parameters have a scope. In this case you are passing `abc` as an argument to the function `mcd()`, but later you trying to access `$1` from outside the function. Apparently `$1` inside the function and `$1` outside the function are two different variables with the same name but different scope and value.

---

Consider this example:

```bash
cat ./script.sh
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

mcd() { echo "Inner: $1"; }

echo "Outer: $1"
mcd "$1"
mcd "Bar"
echo "Outer: $1"
```

```bash
./script.sh "Foo"
```

```bash
Outer: Foo
Inner: Foo
Inner: Bar
Outer: Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

The positional parameter are only assigned a value when done so, e.g. inside a script or when you give parameters to a script you execute.

Matrix already explained it quite well. $1 and all other positional parameters are usually always empty in the current shell.

```bash
guest@porteus:~$ bash
guest@porteus:~$ echo $0
bash
guest@porteus:~$ echo $1

guest@porteus:~$ [Ctrl+D]
exit
guest@porteus:~$ bash TEST
bash: TEST: No such file or directory
guest@porteus:~$ echo $?
127
```

As you can see, you cannot give a random parameter to a new shell (bash in this case) since bash not accepts some random parameter.
What you cannot really see in the above examples, the last attempt to start a 2nd bash failed, if I would press [Ctrl+D] to exit I would exit the only running bash instance - meaning the terminal window or the current tab in my terminal emulator would simply close, since there was not another bash started, the one giving the "return code of 127" info via

```bash
$?
```

is the only running bash, and the attempt to have started a 2nd bash over the initial one did fail (while returning the "127" error code - but you only see error codes when you explicitly ask to be displayed via $? - 0 means no error, anything other than 0 means some kind of error)